# Maven compilation with eclipse compiler fails with false case sensitive name collision between package and type

Tags: maven, case-sensitive, eclipse-jdt, maven-compiler-plugin

Class B

```
package a;

public class B {}
```

Class C

```
package a.b;

public class C {  }
```

Compiler settings

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>

            <configuration>
                <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>

            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Environment: Windows

Expected: compilation pass (mvn clean compile)

Actual: [ERROR] m2\src\main\java\a\b\C.java:[1](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/FAQ#Can_I_use_the_Tycho_compiler_support_in_non-OSGi_projects.2C_too.3F) The package a.b collides with a type

Fortunately, I found already solution [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/FAQ#Can_I_use_the_Tycho_compiler_support_in_non-OSGi_projects.2C_too.3F), but could someone explain me what happens and which compiler is "true" eclipse compiler: plexus-compiler-eclipse or  tycho-compiler-jdt

[repo with example](https://github.com/michaldo/false-name-collision)